# HTML5 Blank Theme WP Admin Bar

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the HTML5 Blank theme from http://html5blank.com but it seems they have removed the WP Admin Bar while you're logged in and browsing the site.

There has been a couple of suggestions to comment out the filter and the remove admin function but this still doesn't seem to work.

This site has redirected me to ask the question here so, where/how can i add the WP Admin Bar back into the theme for logged in users?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Comment out this line in `functions.php` - `add_filter('show_admin_bar', 'remove_admin_bar'); // Remove Admin bar`

Comment: Bah! Thank you, i had seen this and thought i had applied it, maybe not...

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)